# code-signing of a PyInstaller-generated executable on MacOS X not honored

Tags: python, macos, sandbox, pyinstaller

**In the sandbox of os x,My application will call the XPC service that contain one executable file generated by Pyinstaller .But i was told I need code-sign my "Python" file. Can I specify one signed "Python file" when I generate the single executable file? Below is the error :**

`kernel[0]: CODE SIGNING: process 32173 [obfsproxy-xpc-se]: rejecting invalid page at address 0x107be7000 from offset 0x1000 in file "/private/var/folders/nt/j_7h77js7bsfvhw4s44k7cf40000gn/T/com.houlin.obfsproxy-xpc- server/_MEINzOiO6/Python" (cs_mtime:1464339917.0 == mtime:1464339917.0) (signed:1 validated:1 tainted:1 wpmapped:0 slid:0)`

**Now I have code-sign the file,using below code:**

`codesign -f -s "3rd Party Mac Developer Application: lin hou (KF34Q87E4G)" --entitlements /Users/houlin/workspace1/vpn_master/obfsproxy-xpc-service/obfsproxy-xpc-service.entitlements //Python*`

**But,I still get the error below :**

*`16/5/28 下午6:47:42.000 kernel[0]: CODE SIGNING: process 29381[obfsproxy-xpc-se]: rejecting invalid page at address 0x108249000 from offset 0x1000 in file"/private/var/folders/nt/j_7h77js7bsfvhw4s44k7cf40000gn/T/com.houlin.obfsproxy-xpc-server/_MEI4o6uYx/Python" (cs_mtime:1464432462.0 == mtime:1464432462.0) (signed:1 validated:1 tainted:1 wpmapped:0 slid:0) 16/5/28 下午9:26:45.060 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.houlin.obfsproxy-xpc-server[29702]) Binary is improperly signed.`*

**I code-sign the bundle file generated here.**

[image]

**Below is info.plist:**

[image]
[image]

Comment: PyInstaller's wiki covers code signing at https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/wiki/Recipe-OSX-Code-Signing

Comment: (Signing interpreters when that signature confers any kind of privilege escalation is, as a rule, a bad idea, unless the code to be invoked by that interpreter is sufficiently coupled to the binary that an attacker couldn't substitute something else. From what I know about PyInstaller's implementation this constraint is not true, so any code-signed PyInstaller executable could be used as a launching point to run untrusted code [by overwriting contents of its temporary directory prior to execution]... but if Apple isn't turning down such executables, well, it's a free world).

Comment: Yes ,Signing the app bundle and singing the file ("/private/var/folders/nt/j_7h77js7bsfvhw4s44k7cf40000gn/T/com.houlin.obfsproxy-xpc-server/_MEI4o6uYx/Python") Is no use.

Comment: I manually sign the executable file generated by pyinstaller ,and uncheck the option (code sign when copy) in Xcode ,than I brew install python2.11 instead default python interpreters on mac-os,it works finally .Thank you very much .

Comment: The  default python  interpreters on mac-os has some bugs ?

Comment: I experienced this same issue.  When attempting to run the codesigned sandboxed version (signing with entitlements) I get a code sign error as hou lin.  Using python 2.7.13 (DONT install from brew) resolved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try this boiler-plate: https://github.com/The-Nicholas-R-Barrow-Company-LLC/python3-pyinstaller-base-app-codesigning

I use/made it myself. Had similar issues. This projects works perfectly. You can also just modify/copy my "scripts" directory to suit your build workflow.

Comment: For anyone looking in the future, I ended up making a full pip3 library to handle this: ```pymacapp``` which you can try out here: https://github.com/The-Nicholas-R-Barrow-Company-LLC/PyMacApp

Answer (score -3):

Try this recipe. [code signing in pyinstaller](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/wiki/Recipe-Win-Code-Signing)

Comment: this is code signing for windows whereas the question is about OSX